# BroadcastReceiver not showing any Log from onReceive

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, localbroadcastmanager

My service has function

```
broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
public void sendResult(String message) {
    Log.d("Service", "sendResult "+message);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.myandroid.app.messagechanged");
    if(message != null)
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

and `MainActivity` has

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Receiving Broadcast");
        Message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Received : "+Message);
        tvMessage.setText(Message);                       
    }
};
```

and `Manifest` has

```
<receiver android:name="com.myandroid.app.receiver" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.myandroid.app.messagechanged" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This code is not updating `TextView tvMessage`.

Log:

```
Service   sendResult MyMessage
```

Only this log is showing regarding these functions. Not showing any Log from `onReceive`.

My package name is `com.myandroid.app`

Service name is `AppService`

Activity name is `MainActivity`

Comment: You are confusing "manifest" registered receiver classes, with receivers declared & registered dynamically. @Bruno's answer shows how to register the receiver in code\. You can find more info on an answer I placed to a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23154946/383414

Comment: This solution might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464151/logs-logcat-not-working-in-broadcastreceiver/63597388#63597388

Answer (score 2):

Did you register the Broadcast receiver?

You can do it programmatically

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SOME_ACTION");
filter.addCategory("SOME_CATEGORY");
registerReceiver(YOUR_BROADCAST, filter);
```

Or in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name="YOUR_BROADCAST_CLASS" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="SOME_ACTION" />
        <action android:name="SOME_CATEGORY" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I added to manifest file. Still no change. Not showing receive log

Comment: i have changed and my manifest,mainactivity and service is updated in the edits of my post. Please verify and tell if anything gone wrong.