# Logs/logcat not working in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I have a BroadcastReceiver and it there is some problem. The Toast message is showing, and the logcat message is appearing with the command line logcat tool, but not in the Android studio Logcat display. Why? I have already tried `android:debuggable="true"` and anything has not changed.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private String filePath;
        private Ringtone ringtone;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("RECEIVE", "");
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
                filePath = null;
            } else {
                filePath= extras.getString("filePath");
            }
            Log.d("Filepath in receiver", filePath);
            ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, Uri.parse(filePath));
            ringtone.play();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //   setRingsong(context, filePath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean both of the Log messages?

Comment: Yeah, `Log.d("RECEIVE", "");` and `Log.d("Filepath in receiver", filePath);` are not showing.

Comment: Where are you trying to read the logcat? Android Studio, Terminal?

Comment: Android Studio, logcat

Comment: The terminal si ok, just in the Android Studio it is not working.

Comment: Are you filtering based on verbose?

Comment: I met the same issue. Never had this problem before.

Comment: Definitely you have a configuration wrong in Android Studio or you don't know how to read the logs. Please check it carefully before posting. 101% the problem lies in the fact that you have no idea how to view/display log messages.It doesn't matter if it is uppercase or lowercase you should see it if the piece of code is reached.

Comment: Can't see the messages in the Android Studio console, can in a terminal outside of Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this on a shell. adb logcat D |grep RECEIVE
adb program can be found on your sdk  sdk tools(platform-tools)
this is the program the actual debugger use when retreiving the logs.

The "D" parameter indicates that it will show "debug" logs, this complements the android:debuggable="true" setting if you wish to print logs while debugging (remember these are two different things, printing logs with the Log object and setting "android.debuggable = true",check [this link](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) for more information about debugging with AndroidStudio).
Otherwise, try using Log.e function instead of Log.d.
Log.e is usually for errors, in this case for testing purposes you can use it and ensure your logs will always be displayed, due to error logs having a higher priority thatn debug logs.

Comment: The `D` log level has *nothing* to do with `android:debuggable="true"`

Comment: @ChrisStratton you're right, what I ment was that they complement if you wish to do some debugging. But yes, they are not related, they are different tools that you can use together.

Answer (score 0):

1. (`optional step`) At first create a static/const variable named TAG:

   ```
   const val TAG = "aaa"
   ```
2. In Logcat window -> Filters DropDown -> Edit Filter Configuration:

[image]

3. Then in `Log Tag:` field enter the name chosen in the first step:

[image: 2]

You can now log what you want in BroadcastReceiver or anywhere else in your project:

```
class BroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
      context ?: return

      Log.d(TAG, intent?.action!!)
  }
}
```

and the result will be like:

[image: 3]

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the tag should not be all uppercase. If you use "receive" or "Receive", it will be fine.

Comment: That is not true.  Any capitalization pattern is functionally valid in log tags.

Comment: But it is true in my environment: Android Studio 1.3.2. MacBook Pro 10.10.4 and Nexus 5 (5.1.1). I have a sms sending dialog which is using BroadcastReceiver to receive sms sent and delivery intents. I am using adb logcat | grep Sms (sms/SMS) to capture the output. There is no print output for SMS but I can capture sms and Sms tags.

Comment: No, your mistake has nothing to do with the validity of logcat tags, but is more likely because you are using invalid syntax of your argument to a case senstive`grep`.  Try using a case insensitive flag, or passing multiple possibilities with an escape v-bar.  Or trying giving `grep` *only* the uppercase possibility and you will see that it works fine.

Comment: I have double checked my code and called Log.v("SMS", msg); Log.v("Sms", msg); Log.v("sms", msg);  at the same time. Neither Android Studio nor the command adb logcat | grep -i "V/sms" could capture the log with tag "SMS".

Comment: Whatever your issue is, it is *not* with Android.  The source is open for you to read, and it does not apply any such restriction.  Chances are if you just look manually at logs off a typical device, you will see a number of all caps tags flying by.

Comment: Android system is a combination of many things. My suggestion is just a work-around.     Just tried on Note 5 and got the same result. Log.v returns an integer which is undocumented. Further investigation reveals that with all capital tag, the return value is 2X bigger than tags with some lower case characters. I just looked into the source code as well, it is using __android_log_buf_write native calls. I do not really have time to try the native calls at this moment.

Comment: No, your "suggestion" is **irrelevant to the question** - see the poster's own comment that it works fine from the command line in a terminal.  Rather, your problem is likely with the parsing out of tags of interest **on your development machine**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I am off the topic. I tried my situation again with a different tag and the all capital tag "ABB" shows in my log. So, "SMS" looks like a reserved tag for the system.         Log.v("Sms", "test Sms");
        Log.v("sms", "test sms");
        Log.v("SMS", "test SMS");

        Log.v("ABB", "test ABB");
        Log.v("Abb", "test Abb");
        Log.v("abb", "test abb");