# Logcat not working inside onReceive in Broadcast Receiver while listening to deskclock alarm intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am listening to deskclock alarm change intent using my broadcast receiver. When the `onReceive()` method in my Broadcast Receiver is called, the logs `(Log.i/v())` inside the `onReceive` are not getting printed on Android monitor but Toasts are working just fine.

Manifest File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.dumbrella.ratemyday">

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmClockReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class AlarmClockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // This log.v does not get printed on Android Monitor
        Log.v("Broadcast Test", "In Broadcast Listener");

        String message = "Broadcast intent detected "
            + intent.getAction();

        // This toast gets displayed after the alarm is dismissed  
        Toast.makeText(context, message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late, but I leave it for future programmers with this problem, I had a similar problem and solved it this way.
Simply in *Logcat* panel, change the *filtering listbox* to **"No Filters"**.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure that you have **selected the correct device in your DDMS perspective**, also ensure that you have **selected the correct filtering option and log level - in your case you want to select "verbose"**. Also check out the selected answer and suggestions as to why [Logcat is not displaying logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228641/logcat-not-displaying-my-log-calls).

Comment: I am using listening to notifications sent by the same app using another broadcast receiver and log messages are displayed just fine in loagcat. Shouldn't the DDMS perspective affect all receivers in the same application?

I am using a physical device (Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1) to test the code.

Comment: The log were being displayed but not under the filter "Show only selected application". I removed the 'android:process=":remote' tag from the manifest file and then the log started getting printed under ""Show only selected application" filter. Earlier it seems the log was getting printed but getting lost in the myriad of other logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter logs to show BroadcastReceiver logs in LogCat Filter Configuration section:

[image]

The complete solution steps: [Logs/logcat not working in BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464151/logs-logcat-not-working-in-broadcastreceiver/63597388#63597388)