# Android Studio 2.0 log. message not displaying on broadcastreceivers

Tags: android

I am having trouble with my below code, only the toast is displayed but the log message is not.

```
public class SmsSendFakeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.i("TAG", "onReceive:Log-I not Displaying ");
        Log.d("TAG", "onReceive:Log-D not Displaying ");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Toast Displaying",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

I had to believe the app was not working.

Comment: Did you check on your log filter? Set it to "`verbose`" level, and filter for tag called "`TAG`", also make sure you have selected the correct device/emulator on your LogCat.

Comment: This solution might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464151/logs-logcat-not-working-in-broadcastreceiver/63597388#63597388

Comment: better be late than never although 4 years ;-) @Saeid thank you

Comment: @Aelaf :)) you're welcome - I  had this problem and searched for any solution but it was not found, I finally found a solution and told myself to share my experience, it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to clean and rebuild the project.
2. Make sure to select "**verbose**" and remove **tag filter** on your debug log to see all "print out" messages.

Comment: yest its selected verbose... and the tag filter is not set.... the log message on the service class which is broadcasting works it's just on the receiver side. cud it be studio 2.0 bug? ... thanx for the tips again

Comment: is your receiver apart of a service running on a separate process??

Comment: no, i haven't implemented any thread yet, its as simple as a receiver can be.